# Return a list from asyncio function

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following code from below.
I know that probably is wrong somewhere, but how it must be to can return the list telegramlist after it is run?
Just want to can access list items globally?

```
telegramlist = []
telegramchannellist = ['TelethonChat-anti-kyle']


async def telegram_method():
    api_id = '*'
    api_hash = '*'

    client = TelegramClient('trendingsesion', api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()

    telegramdict = {}
    for ch in telegramchannellist:
        channel_username = ch
        channel_entity = client.get_entity(channel_username)
        posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
            peer=channel_entity,
            limit=1,
            offset_date=None,
            offset_id=0,
            max_id=0,
            min_id=0,
            add_offset=0,
            hash=0))
        telegramdict[ch] = posts.messages # here if i write .messages shows a weird error, he want to be only posts
    telegramlist = list(telegramdict.values())
    return telegramlist

shuffle(telegramchannellist)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    telegramlistt = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(telegram_method()))
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `await` in your `main` coroutine. Corrected, it would look like this:

```
async def main():
    telegramlist = await telegram_method()
    return telegramlist
```

Comment: Really thanks for your reply. After i put that await, i get this error message for Python : https://hastebin.com/hoquyapoyu.coffeescript

Comment: And if i remove the last line loop.close() i get : https://hastebin.com/amuziyarez.cs

Comment: @NbaRo You need to also `await` the `client.start()` methods, as well as any other methods that are coroutines.

Comment: I think yes, but i have no ideea how to make it :(

Comment: @NbaRo In the place in your code where you have `client.start()`, just write `await client.start()` instead. That applies to all calls to coroutines.

Comment: I did it. Now, the telegramlistt ( telegramlist is an empty list ) is a [[<coroutine object UserMethods.__call__ at 0x041F1B70>]]
 . How can i read this :"

Comment: @NbaRo Maybe you're missing an `await` in front of `post.messages`?